# Dialog in jquery is not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have written this code but it is not working.

```
$("#dialog-confirm").text("Do you want to submit the new vendor for approval?");
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: true,
        title:"Submit",
        height:170,
        zIndex:99999,
        modal: true,
        position: "center", 
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );            
            return false;
            },

            "No": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );

            return false;
        }
        }
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: check you browser console for any errors

Comment: I'm sure you have missed out the `jquery` and `jquery-ui` js files. Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Seks/206/)

Answer (score 1):

I must use answer,as i dont have permission to comment yet. Your code doesnt look bad,and if you put it to jsfiddle it actually works (at least in chrome). Are you missing reference to jquery or jquery-ui library?

Comment: i only increased height to see whole dialog.